# Is there always an upper limit for which $\int_0^l f(x)\,dx \; < \; \int_0^l xf(x)\,dx,$ is satisfied?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

Given a function $f(x)$ which is strictly positive over all positive values of $x$ such that $f(0) = 0$, it makes sense to me by picturing what happens to $f(x)$ when you multiply it by $x$ that there exists a minimum (and therefore finite) positive $l$ for which the following inequality should be true:

$$\int_0^l f(x)\,dx \; < \; \int_0^l xf(x)\,dx,$$

and consequently would be true taking any value greater than $l$ as the upper limit.

Is this true? If so what is the proof and how would one derive an expression for the minimum $l$  required to satisfy this inequality for any function $f(x)$ which is strictly positive for all positive values of $x$?

To put this in context, I'm considering whether

$$\frac{I}{J} \; < \; 1$$

where $I = \int_0^l r \rho (r) \, dr$ and $J = \int_0^l r^2 \rho (r) \, dr$.

$\rho (r)$ is the linear density of a rod of negligible thickness and $r$ is the distance along the rod from the end. $l$ is therefore the full length of the rod in this case.

Comment: Consider the function $g(l)=\int\limits_{0}^{l}{f(x)}dx-\int\limits_{0}^{l}{xf(x)}dx$ and do a normal max/min argument.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking if $\int_0^l (x-1) f(x) dx >0$ for sufficiently large $l$ when $f(x)>0$.

Take $f(x) = 1/(1+x)^3$. Then, the integral will approach $-1/4$ as you approach $1$ and approach $0$ from below as you approach infinity.

Comment: I should have made clear $f(0)=0$ although I don't think this makes a difference. I have edited the original question.